# How to save XamDiagram in DB?

Tags: .net, wpf, infragistics

I've created `XamDiagram` using `Infragistics` and added nodes into it. But, I am not getting how to save that XamDiagram in DB so that later on I'll be able to edit it. Can you please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think `xamdiagram` currently does not support saving to database. But, instead we can save `binary` data to database so try to save the diagram to some binary format and then upload that binary data to database.
It's the same way you are saving it to your file format but instead of saving it to disk you will be uploading the `FileStream` to your database and then can retrieve the binary file easily from database.

Answer (score 0):

In order to save the information about nodes, connections and their positions, what you could use is the Infragistics Persistence Framework library. In short, the Infragistics Persistence Framework library is used for saving and loading the current state of a control. You could find more information about it in our online documentation - https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/persistence-about-ig-control-persistence-framework.